# How to stop a click propagation for custom react components that are child to MapContainer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I`ve created a custom control react component for map like that:

```
export const MapZoom = () => {
    const map = useMap()
    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        map.zoomIn()
    }

    return (
        <IconButton
            aria-label="clear all figures"
            bgColor="#ffffffe2"
            color="balck"
            onClick={handleButtonClick}
            icon={<FaPlus />}
        />
    )
}
```

I added that component in MapContainer like that:

```
<MapContainer
            center={[51.509865, -0.118092]}
            zoom={10}
            minZoom={2}
            maxBounds={maxBounds}
            maxBoundsViscosity={1.0}
            doubleClickZoom={false}
            style={{
                height: '100vh',
                width: '100vw'
            }}
        >
            <TileLayer url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />

            <MapZoom/>

</MapContainer>
```

If i add to MapZoom that styles: position absolute, zIndex 999, this component will display over the map,  but the main problem if i click at my component, the map will handle this click also.
That make some problems like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI80C.png)
When i use my slider, map reads click and set a circle in wrong way.

I`ve tried to stop click propagation, so map wouldn`t handle that click, also i used react-leaflet-custom-control that worked greate but i couldn`t place my component in center :( So i want to find a solution for this, not a kludge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me , to simply avoid this case, i set a particular attribute to the button. So if it's you who had create the IconButton component, just add a prop like:

```
<IconButton
            aria-label="clear all figures"
            id="btnZoom"
            bgColor="#ffffffe2"
            color="balck"
            onClick={handleButtonClick}
            icon={<FaPlus />}
        />
```

Then you should test this id value in your event action like :

```
const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
        if(e.target.id === "btnZoom"){
            map.zoomIn()
        }
    }
```